# sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot fails to start install F25 and goes back to F24

Tags: fedora, watchdog

I want to upgrade to F25 from F24. I followed these steps:

1. `sudo dnf upgrade --refresh`
2. `sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade`
3. `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --allowerasing --releasever=25`
4. `sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot`

After doing step 4 the following message appeared on the screen:

> sp5100_tco:unexpected close, not stopping watchdog

and after few seconds it goes back to F24.

The output of `lsb_release -a` is

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 25 (Twenty Five)
Release:    25 
Codename:   TwentyFive
```